# No es posible instalar Eclipse (Windows 10 Home 64 bits)

Tags: java, eclipse, windows10, instalacion

he descargado Eclipse y el último JDK y JRE. Estos dos últimos instalados sin problemas pero no así con el Eclipse.
He descargado el instalador "normal" y luego por paquetes e incluso varias veces pero en todos los casos me ocurre lo mismo. Ejecuto el instalable para comenzar la instalación y me sale el error que se puede ver en la imagen. Revisando algo entiendo que el problema podría venir porque mi carpeta de usuario tiene una tilde en mi nombre. Pero siendo la carpeta de usuario sé que no se debe cambiar el nombre y el tema es que el error me salta según hago doble click para instalar el programa y no me da opción a nada.

[image: Error instalación Eclipse]

No sé si alguien me podría echar una mano.

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo,
Víctor.

Comment: prueba crear otro usuario e instalarlo ahi.. si ese es el problema, entonces vas a tener que tenerlo en cuenta..

Comment: Hola gbianchi. Gracias por contestar. Como comento, al hacer doble click ya me salta el error, con lo que no me da opción a cambiar la carpeta de instalación ni nada para probar a instalarlo en otra carpeta de un usuario nuevo.